# Tableau Javascript API workbook.activeSheet()

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I'm probably missing something very obvious here but why does the following not write anything to the log? (jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/qk9cjuh2/ - although it's not working for me)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#tableauViz {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 500px;
}
input[type="button"] {
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://online.tableau.com/javascripts/api/tableau-2.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    // append visualisation container
    d3.select("body").append("div").attr("id", "tableauViz")

    // function to build visualisation.
    function initializeViz() {
        var placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
        var url = "http://public.tableau.com/views/WorldIndicators/GDPpercapita";
        var options = {
            width: placeholderDiv.offsetWidth,
            height: placeholderDiv.offsetHeight,
            hideTabs: false,
            hideToolbar: true,
            onFirstInteractive: function () {
                workbook = viz.getWorkbook();
                activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet();
            }
        };
        viz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
    }  

    initializeViz();

    // switch worksheet function.
    function switchTab(val) {
        workbook.activateSheetAsync(val);
    }    

    d3.select("body").append("input")
        .attr("type", "button")
        .attr("value", "click me")
        .on("click", function() {switchTab("GDP per capita map")})

    console.log(workbook.activeSheet)
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I've built the visualization and then rigged up a button to run a small function that changes worksheet. I can access the workbook object from within that function but there's nothing special about the function that gives it the right to access that workbook object. Why can I not also output info about the workbook object to the log?

The error I receive is 'Reference Error: Workbook is not defined'. If it's not defined how can the function use it?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `workbook` variable is not created until the `onFirstInteractive` callback is called, but your call to `console.log()` is immediately after initializing your `tableau.Viz`.  The act of initializing that object won't cause the callback to be called - that will happen later.

Depending on the reason you're calling `console.log` like that, it might make sense to move that call to the end of the `onFirstInteractive` callback.

Comment: Superb, thanks Richie. I was just querying it out of curiosity - I'm relatively new to js and everyone keeps advising me to write info to the console to make sense of what's going on. So in order to do that I need to make sure the viz is fully 'loaded' first?

Comment: @hwilson1: Yes; the order that your code appears on the screen isn't the order that it runs.  :-)